# How to ensure NSTimer always runs in NSView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` inside a custom `NSView`. The timer is set to always repeat at a specific interval and once it fires, the timer should update a bunch of view parameters.

This all works fine but, when the view is out of focus (i.e. right clicking on the tool bar to pull up a menu), the timer is delayed and does not fire during the time when the view is out of focus.

My question, is how do I ensure that the timer always fires and updates the view parameters even when the view is out of focus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you perform certain events (such as displaying a context menu), the run loop will enter event tracking mode. This means that only certain events will be handled. To get your timer to fire while the run loop is in this mode, include NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode in the list of modes for the timer.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:theInterval target:theTarget selector:theSelector userInfo:theUserInfo repeats:shouldRepeat];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: This was almost my solution. I actually created an NSOperation to hold my timers running concurrently to the main thread.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using this.

Answer (score 0):

one potential explanation:

the timer fires, and the events are added to the queue on time. however, much of AppKit is not thread-safe so... you don't see the update until the next iteration of the run loop. iow, the events are blocked because the events are all piped through the main run loop/thread.

make sense?

note: to make issues even more complex, async drawing is fairly new to os x (at the NSView level), so ensure you test all major versions of the OS you intend to support. results/behavior will vary.

Comment: sometimes you have to drop down to lower level graphics libs and/or use async drawing in your custom view to overcome this.

Comment: I understand. I only support the newest version of OSX. So would you recommend spinning off another thread and draw/update the view on a separate thread?

Comment: well, that's my initial hypothesis - it may not actually be the issue in your case. it's worth proving or disproving before rewriting your ui to operate properly in mt contexts. if that's proven and you absolutely must have that feature then yes, that's the route i'd take. you'd override the 10.6 async methods in NSView. of course, all subviews, overlays, and superviews (if not opaque) must then also be capable of rendering in this context. otherwise, it would just look bad for other reasons (assuming the framework allowed that, which is possible). mt drawing can get complex quickly (cont)

Comment: implementing complex views using CoreGraphics is an alternative if you've a lot of async drawing to do and are comfortable using CG. much of AppKit is objc wrappers on the CG frameworks. however, a complex system like this could mean that you'd rewrite a significant amount of NSView's functionality, depending on your needs. OpenGL is another option, but CG plays better with NSViews, so it's a good middle road for 2d rendering on osx.

Comment: I corrected the problem by subclassing NSOperation and made it run concurrently to the main loop. The NSOperation object holds all my timers. When the timer fires, it tells the view in the main thread to update. Pretty easy. Thanks for the help.